# Data Labels not displaying correctly when sharing PowerPoint via email

Tags: excel, graph, report, powerpoint

I've got a bit of an odd issue with a monthly report I generate.

We have the data in Excel and create the graphs in Excel,  and add labels based on the budget of the item, then we copy the graphs from Excel into PowerPoint and it forms part of the report. When I view the PowerPoint on my screen, all the data (including labels is correct and as expected. 
However when I uploaded the PPT to SharePoint or share it over email, the labels are changing and the taking values from a different cell to the one that they should be.

Not sure if anyone has any ideas on what might be causing this? Or how to get around it?

Thanks

Comment: Copy the graphs into Powerpoint as images instead of Excel objects. Your Powerpoint files will likely be smaller and you'll always get exactly the graph format you want.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.